# Using session ID in ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

I'm trying to use `HttpContext.Session.Id` as a user identifier, so I'm bootstrapping my .NET Core application using:

```
services.AddSession();
...
app.UseSession();
```

However, looking at the [SessionMiddleware](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session/SessionMiddleware.cs,148) it seems the session cookie will only be created if the session is actually used, for example by explicitely calling `HttpContext.Session.SetString(...)`. So, the issue for me is that the cookie `.AspNetCore.Session` is never created. Can I solve this without putting some random value in the session?

Comment: How are you setting Id into session? Can you add that code here?

Comment: You are trying to do something not in the Session realm with Session.  This is why you are in trouble, hehe.  I'd say just generate random GUID's to init the session object.  You have to put something in it.

Comment: @JoséRamírez Yeah, I figured this was the case but there's always hope ;) If you write a answer, I can accept it.